# Як перекласти українською "спустить на тормозах"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Перед тим, як питати тут, пошукав в інтернеті, але жодний російсько-український фразеологічний словник з тих, де мав змогу подивитися, такої статті не має. Хоча я навіть не впевнений, чи правильно назвати такий вислів фразеологізмом.

Онлайн-перекладачі на кшталт Google Translate дають варіант "спустити на гальмах", але він більше схожий на дійсно автоматичний переклад.

Значення можна описати таким чином: "зробити все можливе, щоб справа/подія вщухла сама собою".

Приклад: "попри розголошення у пресі, поліція доклала зусиль, щоб справу спустили на гальмах".

Підкажіть, будь ласка, чи є в українській мові більш влучний аналог?

Comment: Добрий день. Вітаю на українському stackexchange! У нас прийнято надавати пояснення іншомовних висловів, щоби користувачам було легше надати відповідь на питання. Ви могли би це зробити?

Comment: Вітаю! Дякую за пояснення, додав пояснень у питання.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«Спустить на тормозах»/«спустити на гальмах» трактують двома способами:

- уладнати щось неприємне тихо, без шуму
  <sub>(«тормоз» // «Малый академический словарь»: [1](//gufo.me/dict/mas/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7), [2](http://feb-web.ru/feb/mas/mas-abc/19/ma438711.htm));</sub>
- втручаннями припиняти що-небудь (якусь справу і т. ін.)
  <sub>(«спускати» // «Словник української мови» в 11 томах: [1](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), [2](http://sum.in.ua/s/spuskaty)).</sub>

Тобто у першому випадку мені бачиться акцент на тому, що справу **вирішують** (хоча й тихо, бо вона неприємна), а в другому — на тому, що її **припиняють**, не даючи їй вирішитися повноцінно. Мені особисто здається значно правильнішим друге тлумачення. Хоча, можливо, я неправильно трактую перше і/або воно просто неточне.

Ваше тлумачення «зробити все можливе, щоб справа/подія вщухла сама собою» здається мені ідеальним. Але для нього знайти синоніми мені найскладніше.

Російський Вікісловник (посилаючись на «Новые слова и значения. Словарь-справочник по материалам прессы и литературы 60-х годов», але не факт, що саме це твердження звідти) [вважає](//ru.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85&oldid=7534923#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F), що фраза походить із сленгу залізничників. Якщо це так, тобто фраза виникла в радянські часи як професійний сленг, то вона необов'язково є чимось специфічним саме для російської мови (хоча не виключено, що спершу виникла саме там).

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах (див. посилання вище) наводить цю фразу в статті «спускати»:

> Спуска́ти (спусти́ти) на га́льмах — пом’якшувати, полегшувати перебіг чого-небудь; втручаннями припиняти що-небудь (якусь справу і т. ін.).

З іншого боку, цьому словнику часто дорікають за ангажованість, намагання надати українській мові риси російської. Але хай там як, але цю фразу вживали й в українській літературі, наприклад:

> Тепер їм хоч-не-хоч доведеться визначити свою позицію: або піти на радикальний захід — бойкот готелю, — або спустити цю справу на гальмах, обмежившись якою-небудь пустопорожньою декларацією (Артур Хейлі, «Готель», 1930, переклад: Мар Пінчевський, 1972).

> Враження таке, що цю справу свідомо спускають на гальмах (Ліна Костенко, «Записки українського самашедшого», 2010).

***У ПРОЦЕСІ НАПИСАННЯ, ДОПИШУ ПІЗНІШЕ.***

Comment: Дякую дуже за відповідь! Мені саме бракувало прикладів, що "спускати на гальмах" дійсно можна використати, якщо цей варіант є правильним. Але приклади переконали.

Comment: @Zzaponka, можна ще «вирішити/уладнати/утрясти тихо/тишком/тишком-нишком/крадькома/потай», «покласти під сукно / в довгий ящик», «зам'яти», «стопорити», «приховати», «притримати коней» (у різних контекстах).

Comment: @Zzaponka, інші приклади з «на гальмах» (там не всі зі _спускати/спустити_ й не всі в переносному значенні, але частина підходить): http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&iquery=на+гальмах&queryselector=iqueryrow.

Comment: (Я планував писати і про прямий переклад, і про альтернативи, але просто не встиг.)

Comment: дякую ще раз за додаткові варіанти! Як на мене, "покласти під сукно" в цьому випадку також виглядає цілком доречним. І окрема подяка за посилання в коментарі вище. Я і не знав, що є такий скарб на просторах мережі!